# Can't style ActionBar Item?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, togglebutton

I want to style a `ToggleButton` that I placed in my `ActionBar` but I can't seem to do so. I have tried to apply a simple background to it but that doesn't seem to work. I tried to follow this: [Android toggle button custom look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335239/android-toggle-button-custom-look) but that didn't seem to work Here was my attempt:

create_post_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".CreatePost">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/toggle_test"
        android:title="Private"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:background="@drawable/pick_out_line"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ToggleButton" />
</menu>
```

pick_out_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this question : [ToggleButtons as actionBar custom view behaving weirdly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117783/togglebuttons-as-actionbar-custom-view-behaving-weirdly) 
Maybe it can help you for resolve your issue is custion toggle button when setup action bar

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!